# Hiding Two Div Blocks Via jQuery Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a page with two div section initially hidden. Only when a certain element is clicked should those divs show. For whatever reason this is not working as expected, because when the page loads those two sections are showing. Here's my code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#email-sender-div", "#email-recipients-div").hide();
  $("#reporting-menu").on("click", function () {
    $("#email-sender-div, #email-recipients-div").show();
  });
});
```

The two div sections I want to hide on initial page load look like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="email-sender-div">
  <div><label for="email-recipients">Email Sender</label></div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" value="" id="email-sender">
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="email-recipients-div">
  <div><label for="email-recipients">Email Recipients</label></div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" value="">
</div>
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Again, I want these two div blocks to be hidden on initial page load.

Comment: Does something call the function in the first code block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the correct way to include multiple elements in your selector.

```
$("#email-sender-div, #email-recipients-div").hide();
// ----------------^--^ no quotes here
```